# thought after Baby Rudin Ex 5.21: differentiable of all orders; zero on a closed set; but not constant

Tags: real-analysis

I am a newbie to analysis. I did calculus 11 years ago, but am now reading Baby Rudin.

After doing Ex. 5.21 (with the help of the solution), I feel a little upset about my understanding of a few things.

[image]

Consider the function $f(x)=e^{-1/x}$ if $x>0$, and $f(x)=0$ if $x\le0$. The function is differentiable of all orders, and $f^{(n)}(x)=0$ if $x\le0$. Now, I have a few doubts:

1. My understanding is that Taylor expansion can approximate an all-order differentiable function at a local point. Consider $f^{(n)}(-0.1)$, it doesn't seem to approximate $f(0.1)$. Where is my error?
2. If I am ``smoothly'' extending a function from, say, $(-\infty,0)$ to the real line $\mathbb{R}$, it seems that the resulting function is not unique, even if it is all-order differentiable. $f$ as above is an example. Is it really true?

Since I can go through the solution of 5.21 myself, I really need intuitions to help me understand the results. Thank you!

Comment: There's a property called [analyticity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function), which is strictly stronger than being infinitely differentiable, meaning that the function is equal to its Taylor series on some non-trivial interval. This is an example of an infinitely differentiable function that is not analytic (at $0$).

Comment: @TheoBendit, Thank you! Your reference to analyticity shows that my previous intuition of "smooth" extension is too weak. Could you please also correct me on the first point? It seems contradictory, but I can't see where I made a mistake. Thanks again!

Comment: You should also be careful to distinguish between $f^{(n)}(x)$ and the Taylor polynomial approximation at $0$: $$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!} x^k.$$ Even for analytic functions, there's no reason to expect $f^{(n)}(x)$ to approximate $f(x)$.

Comment: @Mou: But in fact, since $f$ is identically zero on $(-\infty,0)$, we have $f^{(n)}(x)=0$ for all $x < 0$, and all nonnegative integers $n$, hence, on the interval $(-\infty,0)$,$f$ is, in fact, analytic, and represented by its Taylor series (the series with all coefficients equal to zero). In particular, $f$ is analytic at $x=-0.1$.